# Why isn't the case statement in my catch working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, switch-statement

My TCP socket data handler works fine in the try block if a client sends JSON.  However, I also wanted to support some basic "terminal commands" over telnet, so if the parser fails the catch block should try to recognize a supported one, but I'm always getting the default response SyntaxError...

```
socket.on('data', function(data){

        try{

            var json = JSON.parse(data);

            switch(json.event){

                default:
                    console.log('unhandled event:'+json.event);
                break;

            }

        }catch(err){

            console.log("CLIENT SAID: "+data);

            switch(data){

                case "echo":
                    socket.write("ECHO:"+data+"\n");
                break;

                case "clients":
                    socket.write("CLIENTS:"+clients.length+"\n");
                break;

                default:
                    socket.write('ERROR:'+err+"\n");
                break;
            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: Instead of `console.log("..."+data)`, try `console.log(data)` and see if `data` is actually a string.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you get the "Syntax error" response? Where do you get that? Where does it come from?

Comment: @Passerby - interesting, it logs <Buffer 68 65 79 0d 0a>

Comment: @Pointy the client receives a message like "ERROR:SyntaxError: Unexpected token c" when sending "clients"

Comment: @E-Madd So it's not a string, thus all your string cases will fail, and always fall back to `default`. It's probably a [`Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not accepting the full response. You should collect data from the stream and wait until the `end` event until the data has been fully received.

```
var body = '';

socket.setEncoding('utf8');
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  body += data;
});

socket.on('end', function () {
  try {
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    switch (json.event) {
      default: console.log('unhandled event:' + json.event);
      break;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("CLIENT SAID: " + body);
    switch (data) {
    case "echo":
      socket.write("ECHO:" + body + "\n");
      break;
    case "clients":
      socket.write("CLIENTS:" + clients.length + "\n");
      break;
    default:
      socket.write('ERROR:' + err + "\n");
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok.  This makes sense, but now nothing I send via telnet is triggering the 'end' event. The body just keeps growing.

Comment: Ah, since the socket stays open, you're going to have to send along a delimiter and mark where a JSON body ends. You can check for the delimiter each time the data event fires.